# Add more space after a dashed rule in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, rules

Following typographic conventions, I'm using a three-em rule in dashed entries in my bibliography. I feel, however, that there is too little space between the rule and the following period.

As the following MWE shows, adding `\space` has no effect (I've also tried `\addspace`, `\(add)thinspace`, and `\hspace{}`, all without effect. How can I add space after the rule?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style = authoryear, dashed = true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*\bibnamedash{\rule[0.48ex]{3em}{0.14ex}\space\addperiod\space}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{smith1965,
    AUTHOR = "Ian Smith",
    TITLE = "The great book about nothing",
    YEAR = "1965"}
@book{smith1972,
    AUTHOR = "Ian Smith",
    TITLE = "I have more to say about nothing",
    YEAR = "1972"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the period?

Comment: @egreg I often use a style in which the entries are formatted like `Smith, Ian. 1965. _Title_.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `\addperiod` gobbles up preceding glue, so `\space` before it does nothing. On the other hand, `\hspace*` tricks it into thinking that *no* space was there, so I can propose

```
\renewcommand*\bibnamedash{\rule[0.48ex]{3em}{0.14ex}\hspace*{.2em}\addperiod\space}
```

which gives

[image]

Adjust to suit. If I use `\hspace*{1em}` (exaggerating the effect), I get

[image]

Comment: I would simply use a real dot . instead of \addperiod.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually, I wouldn't use a period, there.

Comment: Why not? That's a fix output, there is no need to track punctuations or hidden spaces.